# How to delete message in all users using socket.io?

Tags: mysql, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io and mysql (node server)

But I am not successful in delete function.

Here's what I have and what I've tried so far

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `messages`", (err, data) => {
        for(let x in data) socket.emit('message', { id: data[x].message_id, text: data[x].message })
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        // console.log('user disconnected');
    })

    socket.on('add-message', (message) => {
        addMessage(message, (res) => {
            if(res) io.emit('message', { type: 'new-message', text: message}); 
        })
    });

    socket.on('delete-message', (id) => {
        connection.query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `message_id` = '"+ id +"'");
        io.emit('message', { type: 'delete-message', id: id }) // broadcast that something has changed
    })
})
```

Angular2 service

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'

export class ChatService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:5000'
    private socket;

    sendMessage(message) {
        this.socket.emit('add-message', message);    
    }

    getMessages() {
        let observable = new Observable(observer => {
            this.socket = io(this.url);
            this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
                observer.next(data);
            });

            return () => {
                this.socket.disconnect();
            };  
        })

        return observable;
    }

    deleteMessage(id) {
        this.socket.emit('delete-message', id);
    }
}
```

Component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    messages = []
    connection;
    message: any;

    constructor(private chatService: ChatService){ }

    sendMessage(): void {
        this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
        this.message = '';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.connection = this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
            this.messages.push(message);
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.connection.unsubscribe();
    }

    deleteData(id): void {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.messages.length; i++) {
            if(this.messages[i].id == id) {
                this.messages.splice(i, 1)
                this.chatService.deleteMessage(id)

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem of what I have tried:

For deleteData(),
The user who clicked the delete button will have the desired view. But for other users, they must refresh for updated data.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind that you need to store all of your data into the array messages.

The challenging part is the message_id. Since you can't put a value on it. Assuming that it has an auto_increment. We need to add another table column which will have a unique value.

For my example, I will use message_identifier

The table will have (message_id, message_content, message_identifier)

To keep this short. message_identifier will just have time that converted to milliseconds(I believe). You must create a method that will make it completely different.

On your **SERVER**

Getting previous messages

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `messages`", (err, data) => {
    for(let x in data) socket.emit('message', { type: 'get-messages', message: data[x].message, identifier: data[x].identifier })
}
```

Adding message

```
socket.on('add-message', function(message, identifier) {
    connection.query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`message_content`, `message_identifier`) VALUES ('"+ message +"', '"+ identifier +"')", (err) => {
        if(!err) io.emit('message', { type: 'new-message', message: message, identifier: identifier })
    })
})
```

Deleting message

```
socket.on('delete-message', function(identifier) {
    connection.query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `message_identifier` = '"+ identifier +"'", (err) => {
        if(!err) io.emit('message', { type: 'delete-message', identifier: identifier })
    });
})
```

The logic will be on the component. You just need to listen for 'message' and identify through the type that request is passing.

So, here it goes:

Importing socket.io and observable and declaring socket on your component.

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

private socket = io(/* url of server */); // inside AppComponent
```

On your class AppComponent. You need to listen to 'message'

```
let data$ = new Observable(observer => {
    this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        if(data.type == 'get-message' || data.type == 'new-message') {
            observer.next({ message: data.message, identifier: data.identifier })
        } else if(data.type == 'delete-message') {
            for(let i = 0; i < this.messages.length; i++){
                if(parseInt(this.messages[i].identifier) == data.identifier){
                    this.messages.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(data)
    })
})

data$.subscribe(value => {
    this.messages.push(value);
})
```

You can put this on ngOnInit or constructor. I believe it should work either of this two.

On your **SERVICE**

Just remove getMessages since we're handling it on component.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Woooow. Thanks. Worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a message from the client to your nodejs server to delete the message. What you are forgetting at the server side however, is to update al the other clients that something has changed. In your 'socket.on("delete-message")', you should also be sending a message to all connected users to notify them, something has changed. You can do that similarly to the add message:

```
 io.emit('message', { type: 'delete-message', id: id});
```

Btw: Checkout ngrx/store. It's a Redux implementation for angular 2. If you are working with ngrx/store you define actions. Actions are meant to update the client side state. If you were using this, you could just define an action 'DELETE_MESSAGE' and send this action through your socket from server to client. The client would just dispatch this action to ngrx and your UI would update nicely :).

Comment: Yes I know io.emit. I wrote it before but my problem is how do I update the message. Clear the message array object, then try to get again the messages from the db? I will try ngrx/store first. Ugggggh, our instructor doesn't teach us how to use websockets :/